# Show another element when a text is clicked or make :focus display after loosing focus

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My aim is to make the `p` tag with `show` class get displayed when the `span` (with Show Me text) is clicked. I had tried to do this using the `:focus` pseudo-selector but using this method makes the `p` tag get displayed only till somewhere else is clicked, where the `p` tag gets hidden again.

Is there any way to make the `:focus` selector display even after clicking away (or) is there a different/better way (without using JS) to display the `p` when the Show Me is clicked and make it stay that way even after clicking outside?

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Zsnqe/)

HTML CODE

```
<span class="span1" tabindex="0">Show Me</span>
<p class="show" >This will show on click</p>
```

CSS CODE

```
body {
  display: block;
}
.show {
  display: none;
}
.span1:focus ~ .show {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: There would be other ways to achieve this, but not by making `:focus` stick because that isn't what that pseudo is there for, right?

Comment: I can't think any other ways except using JS which I want to prevent to.

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/Zsnqe/1/) is one possibility, but involves changing your markup. Without knowing what the context of usage, I wouldn't recommend this as an answer though.

Comment: Actually this is exactly what I wanted to achieve.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:focus` pseudo-class will not work because, as the naming indicates, it is applicable only when the focus is on the element and there is no way to make the focus 'stick' even after we click elsewhere.

An alternate way of achieving this would be to use the `:target` <sup>[1]</sup> pseudo-class/selector. This would make the `p` display whenever the link is clicked, since it is deemed as 'the target'.

```css
body {
  display: block;
}
.show {
  display: none;
}
#content:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="span1" href='#content'>Show Me</a>

<p class="show" id='content'>This will show on click</p>
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> - [`:target`](http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Atarget) selector is not supported by IE <= 8.